# How does this font manage to display even in plain text?

Tags: encoding, fonts

I came across a piece of text that displays in a mystery font even when you view source in plain text:

The word 'Wood' above appears, at least in Chrome, as a sort of caligraphic font when pasted in to Notepad or even the Google search bar.

Have tried to see if its base64 encoded characters, or quoted printable etc

Can anyone identify how its done? Can it be done with a different font? Is it cross browser compatible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those characters are not being shown in a different font.  They're in the same font as the rest of the page source.

The reason why they look strange is that they are not the ordinary letters 'W', 'o' and 'd' represented by the character values 0x57, 0x6f and 0x64.  These characters are from the "Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols" section of the font.  Specifically they are the "Mathematical Bold Script Capital W", the "Mathematical Bold Script Small O" and the "Mathematical Bold Script Small D" characters represented by the values 0x1d4e6, 0x1d4f8 and 0x1d4ed.  See https://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/mathematical-alphanumeric-symbols/ for a table of the characters in that section.

There's a good chance that any modern browser would show those characters just as you're seeing them.  It comes down to whether the font that the browser uses to present the page includes glyphs for those character values.